# when I open file in emacs I get lots of strange errors

Tags: error, backtrace

My OS is ubuntu 22.04 LTS, `emacs` is in `/usr/local/texlive/emacs-28.1`, texline in `/usr/local/texlive` and `auctex` in `.emacs.d/elpa`. Whenever I open a file in the emacs-buffer, it shows -- in a buffer `*Backtrace*` below the buffer where I opened the file -- the messages below, but after entering `ESC` threee times the file is opened and I can use it as normal. For this session I can close the file in question and open it again as often as i want.

Sample file ist

What do the errors mean and how can I get rid of them?

[image: emacs errors]

Comment: Is your file under version control?  The error is provoked by emacs trying to fire `git` but not finding it.

Comment: IOW, do `apt-get install git` and see if that make the error go away.

Comment: Also, please avoid screen shots unless they are absolutely necessary to show the problem. In this case, it is much better to cut and paste the backtrace into your question literally, by surrounding it with triple backquotes: ```

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is a backtrace, showing you the function calling chain -- most recent at the top -- that led to the (single) error that caused the debugger to be invoked. This helps you isolate the source of the error. You can click on the name of any function to see its code. See the manual: `(info "(elisp) Debugger")` for lots of detail.

Comment: Also, the backtrace will only occur if `C-h v debug-on-error` is enabled.  By default it is not.  You can `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` but, as this is all new to you, something in your config may be enabling it.  If so, you may need to look for that and prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1,

```
;; open files faster but you can't check if file is version
;; controlled. other VCS functionality still works.
(remove-hook 'find-file-hook 'vc-find-file-hook)
```

Solution 2,
Run `apt install git` in terminal. So package `vc` can find git when your project is version controlled by git (you can find a directory `.git` in project root)

I recommend "Solution 1".